# dhcpd snap-in directory not found

Tags: linux, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhclient, dhcpcd

I am running dhcpd on Linux system all the subnets information, reservations n all are written in dhcpd.conf
sometimes we need to make client system's IP static and it will become very difficult to find the subnet & bind it, I want to create separate files for each subnet (like production, staging, clients, etc) but there's no snap-in directory (dhcp.d) in which I can create pool specific files and refer to it whenever I need to make changes something for a specific pool
is there any solution to achieve this ?
or is there any "include" keyword that I can use to integrate other conf files in the main dhcpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the include statement https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf

here is a part of my config:

```
subnet 10.0.43.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.43.100 10.0.43.250;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.0.43.254;
  option domain-name "example.com";
  option domain-name-servers 10.1.10.9;
  option netbios-name-servers 10.1.10.9;

  group {
    filename "undionly.kpxe";
    next-server 10.0.43.252;
    include "/etc/dhcp/hosts.t043";
  }
}
`
```